# PyMongo not returning results on aggregation

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo

I'm a total beginner in PyMongo. I'm trying to find activities that are registered multiple times. This code is returning an empty list. Could you please help me in finding the mistake:

```
rows = self.db.Activity.aggregate( [
    
    { '$group':{ 
        "_id": 
            {
                "user_id": "$user_id",  
                "transportation_mode": "$transportation_mode", 
                "start_date_time": "$start_date_time",
                "end_date_time": "$end_date_time"
            },           
        "count": {'$sum':1}
        }
    },
    
    {'$match': 
        { "count": { '$gt': 1 } }
    },
    
    {'$project': 
        {"_id":0,
        "user_id":"_id.user_id", 
        "transportation_mode":"_id.transportation_mode",  
        "start_date_time":"_id.start_date_time",
        "end_date_time":"_id.end_date_time",
        "count": 1

        }
    }
    ]
    )
```

5 rows from db:

```
{ "_id" : 0, "user_id" : "000", "start_date_time" : "2008-10-23 02:53:04", "end_date_time" : "2008-10-23 11:11:12" }

{ "_id" : 1, "user_id" : "000", "start_date_time" : "2008-10-24 02:09:59", "end_date_time" : "2008-10-24 02:47:06" }

{ "_id" : 2, "user_id" : "000", "start_date_time" : "2008-10-26 13:44:07", "end_date_time" : "2008-10-26 15:04:07" }

{ "_id" : 3, "user_id" : "000", "start_date_time" : "2008-10-27 11:54:49", "end_date_time" : "2008-10-27 12:05:54" }

{ "_id" : 4, "user_id" : "000", "start_date_time" : "2008-10-28 00:38:26", "end_date_time" : "2008-10-28 05:03:42" }
```

Thank you

Comment: please share some sample source documents from `Activity` collection

Comment: have added 5 rows from source

Comment: Your `_id` field in the `$group` query is wrong. I think only `user_id` should be present in `_id` field of `$group` stage

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `_id: 0` in the `$project` stage, it will not project the sub-objects even if they are projected in the follow up, since the rule is overwritten.

Try the below `$project` stage.

```
{
  '$project': {
    "user_id":"_id.user_id", 
    "transportation_mode":"_id.transportation_mode",  
    "start_date_time":"_id.start_date_time",
    "end_date_time":"_id.end_date_time",
    "count": 1
  }
}
```

```
rows = self.db.Activity.aggregate( [
  {
    '$group':{
      "_id": {
        "user_id": "$user_id",  
        "transportation_mode": "$transportation_mode", 
        "start_date_time": "$start_date_time",
        "end_date_time": "$end_date_time"
        },           
      "count": {'$sum':1}
      }
  },
  {
    '$match':{
      "count": { '$gt': 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    '$project': {
      "user_id":"_id.user_id", 
      "transportation_mode":"_id.transportation_mode",  
      "start_date_time":"_id.start_date_time",
      "end_date_time":"_id.end_date_time",
      "count": 1,
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: this did not work

Comment: @MichaelMaier, based on your sample input, the `count` key will never be greater than 1. Have a look at @Joe's answer. Kindly elaborate on what you are trying to achieve with logics and conditions

Comment: Have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Your group criteria is likely too narrow.

The `$group` stage will create a separate output document for each distinct value of the `_id` field.  The pipeline in the question will only include two input documents in the same group if they have exactly the same value in all four of those fields.

In order for a count to be greater than 1, there must exist 2 documents with the same user, mode, and exactly the same start and end.

In the same data you show, there are no two documents that would be in the same group, so all of the output documents from the $group stage would have a count of `1`, and therefore none of them satisfy the $match, and the return is an empty list.